# Sobolev injections

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, continuity

It is true to write that
$W^{1,\infty}(]0,\infty[) \hookrightarrow C([0,\infty[)$ et $W^{1,1}(]0,\infty[) \hookrightarrow C([0,\infty[)$ ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Bazin, your edit significantly alters the original question: in your edit the interval becomes relatively compact (this is significant and much easier than the original version!), and you drop $W^{1, \infty}$ altogether. I must fight the temptation of rolling it back.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Always look at the edit history of a post when it seems not to make sense anymore.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks.  I suggest you roll back the edit.

Comment: @AlexM. I on the other hand succumbs to said temptation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a  fonction in $L^1(0,+\infty)$
with norm 1 and let us define for $x\ge 0$
$$
\phi(x)=\int_x^1f(t) dt.
$$
Then $\phi$ is continuous since
$
-\phi(h)+\phi(0)=\int_0^h f(t) dt,
$
which goes to 0 with $h$ from the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.